# Trying to replicate a tagging system like S.O

Tags: javascript, dynamic, key

I started a Mimic Tagging system like S.O. no it's not going to be exactly the same, and well it can't be done with PHP or anything else. My code will eventually just add the tags to the post and make them look stylish later on with some more JavaScript. Only reason we have to do it this way is because we don't have access to the PHP on the forum hosting provider me and my members use.

Code can be found here

JavaScript:

http://jsbin.com/unoyim/1/

jQuery:

http://jsbin.com/abopaj/1/edit

I started it with jQuery, and a buddy of mine wants me to keep doing Vanilla to get better with it. So I erased it and started with this. This one though is not working on the keypress. Can someone take a look and see maybe I am forgetting something or did I do something wrong here.

I've created all the elements with JavaScript, I think it is the eventListener that is giving me problems honestly.

Comment: My advice would be to not try to deal with the DOM API directly and just use jQuery.

Comment: Well that would be the easy way out wouldn't it :D I want to do this for myself as learning the Core JavaScript will teach me a lot more of the language. I've learned jQuery before JavaScript and I'd rather learn JavaScript for now. Thank you though.

Comment: jQuery *is* javascript. BTW, `addEventListener` isn't implemented in all browsers, and `getElementById` is implemented differently in different browsers. jQuery solves these caveats for you. You're entering a world of pain ;)

Comment: lol. Well for most popular browsers it is correct? or no...

Comment: You can use pure JavaScript (without jQuery) if you want, but you will quickly learn **why** everybody uses jQuery.  Good luck... You're about to have a very large headache!

Comment: lol. I use jQuery, have and always will. Just learning JavaScript makes life easier because some people don't know how to do fade or animations in JavaScript, only jQuery. If I redo this, will you provide help with a width parameter?

Comment: "_Just learning JavaScript makes life easier_ **because** _some people don't know how to do fade or animations in JavaScript..._"  FYI: The fact that some people don't know how to do fades and animations with JS does **NOT** mean that learning JavaScript will make your life easier ;-)

Comment: It does, not just the simple facts on this, but there are many more advantages of learning this. Go do a .each() compared to a for loop and see which is faster. I do for loops even in jQuery because the jQuery .each() is unneeded JavaScript  in the library.

Comment: I've added a jQuery version, just having trouble with the width parameter

Comment: Nevermind I had to do parseInt(ele.width(),10); to make it all work!!!